# How to inherit Binding.StringFormat value with Style in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have many controls that use own binding value like this

```
<TextBox Name="Text1" Text="{Binding Data1}" />
<TextBox Name="Text1" Text="{Binding Data2}" />
<TextBox Name="Text1" Text="{Binding Data3}" />
```

I wanna make same format with the all of my textbox but with different binding textformat if my textbox has focused..

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SomeValue, StringFormat=N2}" />
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SomeValue}" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

How I can make style that inherit from Binding Value before to All my Textbox? thanks..

Comment: I don't think this is possible, use a `Style` for each `TextBox`.

Comment: instead style, use a Behavior or a AttachedProperty.

Comment: @lomed can you give me an example?